# Presenter/View/ViewState relationshipts

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

**For example**, I have `EditProjectFragment` which contains few elements:

- `TextView` (project name)
- `ColorPicker` (project color)
- `Spinner` (project type)

Let's see:

1. Project name will be restored by TextView itself
2. Who must store project's color?
3. Who must store spinner's value?

It seems to be `ViewState`'s responsibility. For example, when user picks color, `View` calls `presenter.onProjectColorPicked(color)`. Then, `Presenter` will call `view.setProjectColor(color)`. Or `View` should update `ViewState` directly, without calling `Presenter` if it doesn't need?

---

**Another example.** User adds photo in EditNoteFragment. User picks photo(`presenter.pickPhoto()`) -> `presenter.addPhoto(photo)` called and notify `View` to add photo to `ViewState`&show it.
Should `View` update `Note` object by itself? Should it be done by Presenter? In the first case it means that `ViewState` will provide methods like `getNote()/setNote(note)` that will be used by View. Should I duplicate Note-reference via updating it in `View.setNote(note)` method? The second case means that I probably should store `Note` object in `Presenter` and just update `View` without passing `Note` in it. But it looks like a wrong way.

---

*In other words:* what `View` must do without `Presenter`'s help(add a photo to `Note` object?) and what things with it(button clicks etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Viewstate was meant to be used to represent different states from your View. I.e The view is displaying a loading indicator. so we could say that the view is in the "loading state". So whenever the "state" changes usually a presenter was involved because its the responsibility of the presenter to coordinate the views state. The question is: how do you define state? There is no silver bullet.

I don't think that it makes sense to play such a ping pong game like

1. `presenter.onProjectColorPicked(color)`
2. `view.setProjectColor(color)`

unless, you say that it goes down to the model (business logic) like this:

1. View calls `presenter.onProjectColorPicked(color)`
2. Presenter calls `model.setColor(color)`
3. model informs presenter (via observer pattern) that the model has been changed
4. Presenter calls `view.setData(newModelWithChangedColor)` containing the new color

In general: the view is just displaying (via presenter) what the current state of the "model" is.

`ViewState` is just a little helper to deal with screen orientation changes and process death in a slightly more convenient way (compared to traditional `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` implementations).

So ask yourself: What is the state of your "model". Usually, the view's state is the same as the state of the "model".

In the first example, it seems that it is an issue of color picker and spinner to not save the the picked things internally. Therefore, doing that manually in `onSaveInstanceState()` for the picker / spinner is the default way the android team recommends to go. So, if you just want to use the `ViewState` feature to not use `onSaveInstanceState()` because you find it more convenient to use ViewState then this is fine too, although it is not exactly what ViewState was meant for.

Comment: > not exactly what ViewState was meant for; 
So, what kind of data must I store in `ViewState`? In fact, I can even keep `List<ProjectType>`&current selected item for `Spinner` via `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.